# How can I change strings into ints with enums? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enums

I have a problem. I have quite big multistep form where I assign string to the state, the thing is, my backend(friend of mine is in charge of it) takes ints. I have heard that it is possible to change strings into ints so I could successfully send a request to backend without getting error 400.
State looks like this:

```
state = {
selectMode: "",
selectCurrentDivision: "",
selectCurrentTier: "",
selectFutureDivision: "",
selectFutureTier: "",
TypeOfService: "",
Extras: ""
}
```

How could I use enums to assign specific string to specific number? For example: FirstMode = 1, SecondMode = 2, ThirdMode = 3

Comment: If you are using typescript, take a look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). If not, what about `{ selectMode: 1, selectCurrentDivision: 2, ...}`?

Comment: @A_A Yeah Im using typescript, I will look into it. Changing the whole state into ints would make a mess in code because in my switch/case form I have something like:
" if(selectMode === "FirstMode") { ..... } ", "if(selectMode === "SecondMode") { .... }"

Comment: The simplest solution would be to keep your component state independent of the backend requirements. Simply create the request per spec given your local state only when required (basically an [*Anti-Corruption Layer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer)). This gives you all the freedom to develop your component as you need. And you still only have one place to look (the transformation code, that creates the request) if changes are required (front- or backend).

Comment: Im not sure if I understand correctly but if I will keep the state independent of the backend requirements(which I do right now I think?) then I will still be getting error 400 while trying to send a request.
For now I have: axios.post("Order", { selectMode: this.state.selectMode, selectCurrentDivision: this.state.selectCurrentDivision })..... and I keep getting error 400 because I send strings to backend which has ints in there, right?

Comment: With: `axios.post("Order", { selectMode: this.state.selectMode, selectCurrentDivision: this.state.selectCurrentDivision })` see how you directly and indiscriminately pass state values to the request? That's where you're dependent on the backend requirements. A better way would be to transform the component state to a valid request. For example with a transformation function (e.g. `createBackendRequestFromState(...)`). You supply the component state to that function and it returns a valid request. This in turn gives you the freedom to change your component state when required or react to...

Comment: ... changes on the api side. What this function does can be quite simple to start with. For example simply mapping required values and converting them to the required types. The take away here is to consciously create a *seem* between the two layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both, string and int values for the enum, you could map the typescript enum like this:

```js
enum Mode {
  First = 'FirstMode',
  Second = 'SecondMode',
  Third = 'ThirdMode',
}

const modeToInt: { [K in Mode]: number} = {
  [Mode.First]: 1,
  [Mode.Second]: 2,
  [Mode.Third]: 3,
}

function fetchAPI(mode: Mode) {
  const n = modeToInt[mode]
  return `https://example.org/${n}`
}

const state: { mode: Mode } = {
  mode: Mode.First,
}
console.log(state.mode) // FirstMode
console.log(fetchAPI(state.mode)) // 1
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsg9gE2FA3gWAFBSgMQJYBOAzgC5QC8UA5PsSfElQDSbYDKwAxnCAhdR268GwZqygAVABaE+lKtNkixGAL6ZMQ0lAiJgEuAEkQJAFyooAbQDSUPCFh6AuufAQARsAKr+6LFZEAOlpSFygARhZ-SyDBHgQwgCYo7Bi9QMUCBPMAZij1DEwAMzAQThI8Higi4BJOKQBBAAVDAApdJHMRAEpUcS0yB0oO-SMTSxGncQJasAIHAAMpEhIAByJTAHpN4AAPAEMIVYAbYEC4AgBzTYASFBBVBcwCzR5tUn2SYHMUHT0uvRQHyUPzYEYApDBQikfKvEBEOCnQLHOCXVofL6BEbdOEIpEotE1OqNFrokifM7Y7pAA)

If you only need the number representation, just use the numbers directly in `enum Mode` instead of the string.